# MySQL - replace text with keywords/values from a sub query

Tags: mysql

I have a table #1 with a text field.
This field contains a paragraphs of text
In the content, I put some placeholder like "[[the_president]]"

I have a table #2 with 2 fields: key and value.
Key is the "[[the_president]]" and the value is "Abraham Lincoln"

How can I write in a single query to make the result of table #1 the placeholder replaced by the values of table #2?

Thanks

Comment: Does it need to be done in SQL? It would be a simple task in (almost) any procedural language.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `REPLACE()` function after joining the two tables.

```
SELECT REPLACE(t1.textfield, t2.key, t2.value) AS new_textfield
FROM Table1 AS t1
JOIN Table2 AS t2 ON LOCATE(t1.textfield, t2.key) != 0
```

Note that this will only work for one placeholder at a time. If a text field contains multiple placeholders, you'll get a different result row for each replacement, they won't be combined.

I think you might be able to get multiple replacements using a [recursive CTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive), but CTE is only available starting with MySQL 8.0, and I'm not familiar with them. From what I can tell, the recursive CTE will return all the intermediate replacements in addition to the final combined replacement; I'm not sure how to filter those out.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The table #2 is a database of placeholders. I would like the replace to any placeholders found in table #1 by the appropriate value.

Comment: That's what this does.

Comment: I want them combined in the same row. Not row for each replace.

Answer (score -2):

you can use like this
 select the_presiden as

Comment: You left out most of the answer.